# Threading and events

Tags: java, android, multithreading, events

I'm really stuck here, I've read a lot on threading on android but I'm unable to find an answer that suits my proyect.

I've got a frontend (Manages GUI) and a backend (Manages the data and stuff). I need to update the GUI as soon as the backend finishes running a thread but I can't figure out how!

`Main.java` package frontend

```
public class Main extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Server server = new Server(getApplicationContext());
        }

    };
    thread.start();
```

`Server.java` package backend

```
public static List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
public Server(Context context) {
    Revisar archivo = New Revisar();
    archivo.DoSomething();
}
```

After `archivo.doSomething` finishes I need to update the GUI with the backend data stored in the static list.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've surmised, you can't update the GUI from a background thread.

Typically, to do what you want, you use the message handling mechanism to pass a message to the GUI thread. Typically, you pass a [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) which will be executed in the GUI thread. You can also pass a [Message](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) if you've subclassed the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and added code to deal with messages.

Messages are passed to Handlers. You can either create your own Handler in the GUI thread, or use one of several that already exist. For example, every View object includes a Handler.

Or you can simply use the [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)() Activity method.

Pattern 1, handler plus runnables:

```
// Main thread
private Handler handler = new Handler();

  ...

// Some other thread
handler.post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Log.d(TAG, "this is being run in the main thread");
  }
});
```

Pattern 2, handler plus messages:

```
// Main thread
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    Log.d(TAG, "dealing with message: " + msg.what);
  }
};

  ...

// Some other thread
Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(what);
handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

Pattern 3, call runOnUiThread():

```
// Some other thread
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {      // Only available in Activity
  public void run() {
    // perform action in ui thread
  }
});
```

Pattern 4, pass a Runnable to a View's built-in Handler:

```
// Some other thread
myView.post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // perform action in ui thread, presumably involving this view
  }
});
```

Comment: In all of the patterns you mentioned, all the threads are running in the Main activity. My problem is the thread is running on another class and in another package

Comment: You mean an entire separate application?  Or a service?

Comment: Almost entire separate application. I use the backend to handle the data as I was taught that you should always try to use MVC. So the backend is a package with 2 classes that help me with handling data.

Comment: Yeah, that makes things a bit more complicated. My answers are relevant if you're launching threads from the main activity. If your threads are running in an entirely different package (e.g. a service) or even a whole different process or application, then it gets hard. Basically, your other process will have to send Intents to your activity requesting that the UI be updated.